# API platform Boolean filter default value

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I registered kind of boolean filter for my ressource:

```
    app.my_dummy_resource.boolean_filter:
        parent:    'api_platform.doctrine.orm.boolean_filter'
        arguments: [ { 'dummyBoolean': true} ]
        tags:      [ { name: 'api_platform.filter', id: 'my_dummy.boolean' } ]
```

By default, false is the value of my filter when I call my resource without specifying the `dummyBoolean` filter.

I want the value to be *true* as a default value for my 'dummyBoolean' filter.

Comment: I think you might not achieve this with `arguments`. 
You have to create your own doctrine extension and apply filter on query builder when `dummyBoolean` is not present in the filter context. 
Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761690/how-to-always-filter-a-collection-on-specific-field-value-in-api-platform-get-op